# Simply-connected Lorentzian manifold and event horizon

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

Can a simply connected Lorentzian manifold admit an event horizon? Or does the event horizon makes it non-simply connected?

Comment: What is an event horizon on a Lorentzian manifold?

Comment: I suppose the Schwarzschild metric on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R_+} \times \mathbb{S^2}$ admits an event horizon in whatever definition you want to use? The manifold is simply connected because $\mathbb{S^2}$ is.

Answer (score 1):

As [aes said](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1055064/simply-connected-lorentzian-manifold-and-event-horizon#comment2148870_1055064), the Schwarzschild solution is simply connected and admits an event horizon.

(Posting as CW for the sake of giving this question an answer.)

Comment: Hi Willie. Could you kindly provide a mathematical definition of an event horizon in an arbitrary space-time manifold, including a non-time-orientable one? I am guessing that an event horizon exists whenever there is a region of space-time that contains the future light-cone of each point in it.

Comment: @Transcendental: event horizons are not locally defined. They are global quantities that can only be defined for Lorentzian manifolds with a well-defined notion of "asymptotic region". This include all asymptotic flat manifolds. The whole motivation of event horizons (regions of no escape) depends on a direction of time (you can fall into a blackhole, but not come out of it), and it makes absolutely zero sense to ask for a definition of event horizon on a "non-time-orientable" Lorentzian manifold.

Comment: @Transcendental: A formal mathematical definition looks something like this: let $(M,g)$ be a Lorentzian manifold. Assume that it is time-oriented. Declare a subset $R \subset M$ the "asymptotic region". Then the event horizon of $M$ relative to the asymptotic regions $R$ is the set $\partial (M\setminus J^-(R))$, where $J^-$ denotes the causal past. // Usually one speaks of event horizons for asymptotically flat manifolds, in which case we can take $R$ to be formally a small neighborhood of "future null infinity". If you really want to find out more about the mathematics, I suggest you...

Comment: ... look at a standard textbook like Wald's _General Relativity_.